# Python 3.5: Passing a string as parameters to the subprocess procedure

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, parameter-passing

I am using python 3.5 on a rasbian pi linux system. I am still new to it, but do have some coding experience in vba.

My problem is this. The following lines of code work fine:

```
#working
import subprocess
chrome = "chromium-browser"
site="www.ebay.com.au"
proc=subprocess.Popen([chrome,site],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
leaf1="leafpad"
leaf2="--display"
leaf3=":0.0"
leaf4="/home/pi/Documents/leaftxt.txt"
proc=subprocess.Popen([leaf1,leaf2,leaf3,leaf4],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This code successfully opens Chrome to ebay, then a text editor called leafpad with the text file leaftxt.txt open in it.

But when I try this process loading the parameter strings from a text file, I get an error:

```
#not working
import subprocess
tasks="/home/pi/Documents/tasklist.txt"
try:
    f=open(tasks,"r")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File Not found.')
    sys.exit()
for x in f:
    x1=x.strip('\n')
    proc=subprocess.Popen([x1],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The errors raised is as follows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):    
    File "/home/pi/Documents/P3Scripts/test7.py", line 19, in <module>      
proc=subprocess.Popen([x1],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)    
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__      
restore_signals, start_new_session)   
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child       
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)  
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromium-browser, www.ebay.com.au'
```

The text file tasklist.txt contains (I have also tried without commas)

```
chromium-browser, www.ebay.com.au
leafpad, --display, :0.0, /home/pi/Documents/leaftxt.txt
```

Both files appear to be doing the same thing but I am missing something in the formatting of the parameters as they are used in the second subprocess procedure call.

What am I missing/doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between

```
Popen(["foo", "bar"])        # correct: you parse arguments
```

and

```
Popen("foo bar", shell=True) # correct on POSIX: shell parses arguments
```

and

```
Popen(["foo, bar"])          # incorrect: noone parses arguments
```

---

In your first snippet, you use the first form: the program name and each argument as a separate element of a list.

In your second snippet, you use the third form: because you are using the array, `Popen` believes you have already separated the arguments, and the entirety of the first argument is the name of the program to be executed. Of course, a program named `chromium-browser, www.ebay.com.au` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are passing four strings, while in your second example, one string containing all four.

You should split it up:

```
x1=x.strip('\n').split(', ')
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error message - ëxpects bytes or str, not list

Comment: Did you still use `[x1]`, or just `x1`? If you used `[x1]`, then Popen got a double list: `[["chromium-browser", "www.ebay.com.au"]]`, and was complaining that its first element was not a string.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help shx2!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import subprocess
tasks="/home/pi/Documents/tasklist.txt"
try:
    f=open(tasks,"r")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File Not found.')
    sys.exit()
for x in f:
    x1=x.strip('\n').split(", ") #split_str_list is a list that contains string of single line in /home/pi/Documents/tasklist.txt
    proc=subprocess.Popen(x1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You passed a string contains arguments that separated with comma.
Popen does not accept it.
Popen args should be a string it must be separated with space, or sequence of argument.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen